# Google Cloud Run API - accessing endpoint internally

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Bear with me, I am still on training wheels with GCP

Scenario being

1. I have a Cloud Run instance serving an API (to be consumed internally)
2. A middleware running on Cloud Compute instance serving an API. This utilises API served by (1)

(2) needs to access (1)

I'm trying to figure out how to discover the internal DNS name or IP, so that the middleware (2) can be configured to access Cloud Run served API (1)

Intention being to create templates (environment config files) so that I can eventually automate the deployment of all layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Cloud Run, you can't know before the first deployment the URL of the service. The pattern is

```
https://<serviceName>-<projectHash>.<region>.run.app
```

*You can also have optionally a tag at the beginning, but it's not important here*.

The bad part is the project Hash can't be calculated before the deployment (or I donc know the hash formula). Thus it's impossible to register in a DNS the URL in advance of the deployment.

---

However, if you use tools like [terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_run_service), you can get, as output, the URL of the service after the deployment and then register it in your DNS, as CNAME (Cloud Run is a managed service, you haven't a static IP).

---

You can also use the [CLoud Run API](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest) to request the [list of services](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.services/list) on a project, pick the service that you want and get the URL of the service ([get request to the service API](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.services/get))

---

A last word before you hit the wall, you talk about internal endpoint. Cloud Run url is public, and public only. Therefore, your middleware need to access to the internet to be able to request Cloud Run.

If your middleware is deployed on the same project, you can set the Cloud Run service [ingress to internal](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/ingress) to allow only resources from the VPCs of the current project to access to Cloud Run service.

But the URL is still public and you need an internet access to resolve and to access it.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this.

I also happened to stumble across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65522752/access-cloud-run-from-compute-engine-in-internal-ingress-mode) from Feb - where GCP support mentioned that calling Google Run hosted API endpoints using private IP is currently not possible; but it's something on the cards. Right now, it appears, all calling hosts must have internet connectivity to be able to call Cloud Run hosted endpoints (just as you've pointed out)

Fingers crossed this gets implemented soon ..

Comment: I doubt that internal IP connectivity will be implemented a day.... However, in you subnet, in your VPC, you can check the private google access. That allow all resources (VM) in this subnet to reach publicly available Google Cloud resource without having access to the wild internet directly. It's a kind of special road for Google Cloud services.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wanna be bothered by service discovery and constructing the full URL, you can use [runsd](https://github.com/ahmetb/runsd), a solution that I developed for Cloud Run that allows you to call a service by its name (e.g. http://hello).